# SQL Server: How to select the second to last entry given a group of items?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with five columns:

- mykey (INT pk)
- name(VARCHAR)
- otherdata (VARCHAR)
- groupID (INT)
- date DATETIME
- active (INT)

Sample data:

```
mykey   name        otherdata   groupID  date      active
----------------------------------------------------------
1      123_abc_nt   cat         1        6-6-16    0
2      123_abc_nt   dog         1        6-7-16    0
3      123_abc_nt   car         1        6-8-16    1
4      123_xyz_nt   red         2        6-9-16    0
5      123_xyz_nt   blue        2        6-10-16   1
```

All entries in this table are grouped by `groupID` and name. In other words, if a name is 123_abc_nt, the group will be group "`#insertgroupidhere`". Due to the nature of the process that uses this table (which I can not change in any way), any change to either the "name" or "otherdata" column will produce a new row.

So say a user changes row 5 column "otherdata" from `blue` to `green` from a separate application that uses this table. In this case, that separate application will produce a **new** row: `6, 123_xyz_nt, green` and mark the old column as not active `0`.

```
mykey   name        otherdata   groupID  date      active
-----------------------------------------------------------
1      123_abc_nt   cat         1        6-6-16    0
2      123_abc_nt   dog         1        6-7-16    0
3      123_abc_nt   car         1        6-8-16    1
4      123_xyz_nt   red         2        6-9-16    0
5      123_xyz_nt   blue        2        6-10-16   0 <--- old row deactivated
6      123_xyz_nt   green       2        6-11-16   1 <--- new row inserted and activated
```

This will occur to changes for ANY column in the table. So if I change name from _nt to _rt, the table will look like this:

```
mykey   name        otherdata   groupID  date      active
---------------------------------------------------------
1      123_abc_nt   cat         1        6-6-16    0
2      123_abc_nt   dog         1        6-7-16    0
3      123_abc_nt   car         1        6-8-16    1
4      123_xyz_nt   red         2        6-9-16    0
5      123_xyz_nt   blue        2        6-10-16   0 
6      123_xyz_nt   green       2        6-11-16   0 <--- old row deactivated
7      123_xyz_rt   green       2        6-12-16   1 <--- new row inserted and activated
```

I need to write a query that will specifically detect this name change from `_nt` to `_rt` (or vice versa from `_rt` to `_nt`) and return the **active** row that has inccured this change. So in the last situation my query would need to return `7, 123_xyz_rt, green, 2, 1`. Also, it needs to ignore any other column changes and only detect the nt/rt name column changes. There can be situations where I have multiple rows change at once also, and my query needs to detect this.

Example:

```
mykey   name        otherdata   groupID  date      active
----------------------------------------------------------
1      123_abc_nt   cat         1        6-6-16    0
2      123_abc_nt   dog         1        6-7-16    0
3      123_abc_nt   car         1        6-8-16    0  <-- deactivated
4      123_xyz_nt   red         2        6-9-16    0
5      123_xyz_nt   blue        2        6-10-16   0 
6      123_xyz_nt   green       2        6-11-16   0 
7      123_xyz_rt   green       2        6-12-16   0  <-- deactivated
8      123_xyz_nt   green       2        6-13-16   1  <-- activated
9      123_abc_rt   car         1        6-13-16   1  <-- activated (note the groupID)
```

I've been trying to nail down a query that does this but it's been exceedingly difficult. I cannot use triggers on the table in this database either so this needs to be strictly query based. Here is what I have attempted:

I have a temp table that catches any newly inserted rows:

```
DECLARE @NEWROWS_TEMP TABLE(mykey, name, active)

INSERT INTO @NEWROWS_TEMP
--PROCESS TO CATCH NEW ROWS....
```

Then with that list, I am trying to find rows that have changed names in a while loop:

```
--Loop Variables:
DECLARE @TOTALCOUNT INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TEMP)
DECLARE @NAME_INVERTED VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @LOOPNUM INTEGER = 1
DECLARE @CURRENT_KEY INT = 0

--Loop to find entries that changed from (nt->rt) OR (rt->nt):
WHILE ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TEMP) > 0 AND (SELECT @LOOPNUM) <= @TOTALCOUNT)
BEGIN 
    SET @CURRENT_KEY = (SELECT TOP 1 mykey FROM @TEMP)
    SET @NAME = (SELECT name
                FROM @TEMP 
                WHERE CLASSIC_KEY = @CURRENT_KEY)
    SET @NAME_INVERTED = (SELECT CASE WHEN (CHARINDEX('_rt_',@NAME)  > 0)
                        THEN 
                            REPLACE(@NAME,'_rt_', '_nt_')
                        ELSE 
                            CASE WHEN (CHARINDEX('_nt_',@NAME)  > 0)
                            THEN 
                                REPLACE(@NAME,'_nt_', '_rt_')
                            ELSE
                                NULL
                                END
                        END)

    IF(EXISTS(
                SELECT TOP 1 mykey
                FROM mytable
                WHERE name = @NAME_INVERTED AND 
                active = 0)
             )
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @RESULT_LIST
            SELECT @CURRENT_KEY
        END 

    DELETE FROM @TEMP WHERE mykey = @CURRENT_KEY
    SET @LOOPNUM = @LOOPNUM +1
END
```

This works except for situations where a row's name never changed but `otherdata` did and a past nt-rt change exists. The loop just skips over the fact that the row's name did not change.

So for example, if I do this:

```
mykey   name        otherdata   groupID  date      active
----------------------------------------------------------
1      123_abc_nt   cat         1        6-6-16    0
2      123_abc_nt   dog         1        6-7-16    0
3      123_abc_nt   car         1        6-8-16    0  
4      123_xyz_nt   red         2        6-9-16    0
5      123_xyz_nt   blue        2        6-10-16   0 
6      123_xyz_nt   green       2        6-11-16   0 
7      123_xyz_rt   green       2        6-12-16   0  
8      123_xyz_nt   green       2        6-13-16   1  
9      123_abc_rt   car         1        6-13-16   0  
10     123_abc_rt   bike        1        6-13-16   1 <-- Name did not actually change. Otherdata did, but current query picks this up anuway since there once was a change from "123_abc_nt" to "123_abc_rt"
```

Is there a much easier way to get a similar result without using a loop? My method is proving to be highly inaccurate and hard to maintain.

Comment: There's always only a single row (the latest) per group where `active = 1`? And you want to return it when the previous row has a different name?

Comment: Absolutely correct, there is always only one active row per group. Thats a hard rule. I only ever want to return when the previous row has a name change (specifically either `_nt` to `_rt` or vice versa). All else, I don't care about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should return the expected result, check the name of the previous row with `active=0` if it's different:

```
select * from mytable as t1
where active = 1
and name <>
 ( select top 1 name
   from mytable as t2
   where t1.groupID = t2.groupID
     and active = 0
   order by t2.date desc
 )
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this shuold work. Very simple! I'll give it a try. It's so many times simpler than my previous implementaion.

Comment: I had to highly modify this to fit my exact table structure, but the basis of this query worked absolutely perfect, you rock!  I now have just this one query with a nested subquery doing everything that ugly while loop attempted to do (but failed to do). Thanks again.